# Fix a soft-bricked Nexus 4 without usb?

Tags: usb, unbricking, twrp

My Nexus 4 is soft-bricked, when I turn it on normally it just stays stuck on the "Google" logo.
The device has TWRP recovery v2.8.0 installed, which can be accessed.
The device's USB does not work, I think it's a hardware problem.

Is there any way to fix a phone in this state?
Perhaps send an installable rom zip over Wi-Fi or Bluetooth?
I'd be glad to hear any suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried a factory reset? When did this happen?

Comment: How can I do a factory reset? The phone won't boot.. I think it got into this state when I accidentally wiped everything from the phone and didn't have a rom to install.

Comment: You can do a factory reset within TWRP.

Comment: The problem is, I think I wiped the system partition, so there's nothing installed on the phone right now. I think the only solution would be to send an installable zip. Could it be possible to transfer a file to the device without usb?

Comment: Not that I know of without booting the phone. Have you tried connecting it on different computers? What happens when you plug in an OTG cable?